# How to get more parameters when url-rewriting block it?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

There's the thing :

I have this Url Rewriting condition in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+) app.php?pattern=$1&content=$2 [L]
```

Then, it works perfectly with this url for exemple : 
`www.mysite.com/pony/mycontent`

But when I try to add some Http GET parameters like that :
`www.mysite.com/pony/mycontent?moreparameter=true`

The var_dump($_GET) return me :

```
array (size=2)
  'pattern' => string 'pony' (length=4)
  'content' => string 'mycontent' (length=8)
```

And no more values ..

How to retrive the other parameters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try adding the "query string append" flag (QSA) to your [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) -

```
RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9]+)... app.php?pattern=$1&content=$2 [QSA,L]
```

> **QSA|qsappend** - When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

[Read more here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Comment: Thanks, it works ! But carefull, there is no space between "[QSA," and "L]"

Comment: @flo - did that space cause a problem with your server?

Comment: @flo - wow... good to know! Apparently apache doesn't care for readability ;)